# Out of sample prediction in statsmodel with NaN values

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I have a dataset which is comprised of various values concerning auto_sales in the USA.

I'm trying to predict the auto_sales for October 2010 using a simple OLS regression.

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv('Paul_data/question12_prediction_data.csv')
window_size = 7                                              #-1 due to zero-indexing of array
window = df2.ix[0:window_size,:]
print window

result = sm.ols(formula="log_sales ~ log_sales_l2 + vehicleshopping_l2 + vehiclebrand_l2 + actual_sales_edmunds_l1 + isSummer + isWinter", data=df2).fit()
print result.predict()[df2[(df2.month == 10) & (df2.year == 2015)].index[0]]
```

window is the following data:

```
year  month  auto_sales  log_sales  log_sales_l1  log_sales_l2  \
0  2015      3       83352  11.330828     11.294807     11.317823   
1  2015      4       83871  11.337035     11.330828     11.294807   
2  2015      5       85489  11.356143     11.337035     11.330828   
3  2015      6       84123  11.340035     11.356143     11.337035   
4  2015      7       85320  11.354164     11.340035     11.356143   
5  2015      8         NaN        NaN     11.354164     11.340035   
6  2015      9         NaN        NaN           NaN     11.354164   
7  2015     10         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN   

   log_sales_l3  GT_vehicleshopping  GT_vehiclemaintenance  GT_suvs  \
0     11.313523              0.1320                  0.694   0.0680   
1     11.317823              0.1150                  0.745   0.0525   
2     11.294807              0.1060                  0.754   0.0560   
3     11.330828              0.0950                  0.785   0.0550   
4     11.337035              0.1025                  0.870   0.1075   
5     11.356143              0.1140                  0.794   0.1240   
6     11.340035                 NaN                    NaN      NaN   
7           NaN                 NaN                    NaN      NaN   

          ...          vansminivans_l2  isWinter  isSummer  vehiclebrands  \
0         ...                   0.0900         1         0           0.08   
1         ...                   0.1250         0         0           0.09   
2         ...                   0.1580         0         0           0.09   
3         ...                   0.1750         0         1           0.12   
4         ...                   0.1920         0         1           0.17   
5         ...                   0.2100         0         1            NaN   
6         ...                   0.2175         0         0            NaN   
7         ...                      NaN       NaN       NaN            NaN   

   vehiclebrand_l1  vehiclebrand_l2  actual_sales_edmunds  edmund_forecast  \
0             0.05             0.03               1542841          1522881   
1             0.08             0.05               1451790          1464176   
2             0.09             0.08               1631234          1591221   
3             0.09             0.09               1473142          1484487   
4             0.12             0.09               1507643          1478025   
5             0.17             0.12               1573573          1538958   
6              NaN             0.17                   NaN              NaN   
7              NaN              NaN                   NaN              NaN   

   actual_sales_edmunds_l1  edmund_forecast_l1  
0                  1255458             1285019  
1                  1542841             1522881  
2                  1451790             1464176  
3                  1631234             1591221  
4                  1473142             1484487  
5                  1507643             1478025  
6                  1573573             1538958  
7                      NaN                 NaN  

[8 rows x 32 columns]
```

However I get the following error:

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-16bf72335e7f> in <module>()
      5 
      6 result = sm.ols(formula="log_sales ~ log_sales_l2 + vehicleshopping_l2 + vehiclebrand_l2 + actual_sales_edmunds_l1 + isSummer + isWinter", data=df2).fit()
----> 7 print result.predict()[df2[(df2.month == 10) & (df2.year == 2015)].index[0]]
      8 #np.exp(result.predict(df2.ix[x+(window_size)]))

IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

I'm not sure how to proceed at this point, I understand that I am trying to do out of sample prediction but everything I've tried so far has failed to solve the issue.

Comment: OLS can predict for given explanatory variables. To me it looks like the mistake is that the prediction data for the explanatory variables is not in the call to predict, i.e. check parenthesis `result.predict([df2[(df2.month == 10) & (df2.year == 2015)])`. predict without arguments returns the `fittedvalues` for the sample that was used in the estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, I believe, is that the data over which you are regressing only has 5 entries in which not all the input is NaN. Therefore this:

```
result.predict()
```

Returns an array of 5 elements, but this:

```
df2[(df2.month == 10) & (df2.year == 2015)].index[0]
```

returns '7', as the slicing you are performing returns one row, which corresponds to the 8th row in your original dataframe. So you are asking "give me the 8th element of this array of length 5" and it therefore breaks.

Comment: Am I correct that it should theoretically be possible to predict out of the sample using the regression established by using the rows that are populated?

Comment: sure, that is indeed the point. When you call predict() with no arguments, you are using your estimated parameters over the data you used for the fit. In your original case, that returned a list of 5 predictions. In your edit, you are now explicitly telling statsmodels over what data it should do the prediction

Answer (score 0):

user333700 was correct, this solved my problem:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('Paul_data/question12_prediction_data.csv')
window_size = 4                                              #-1 due to zero-indexing of array
window = df2.ix[0:window_size,:]

result = sm.ols(formula="log_sales ~ log_sales_l2 + vehicleshopping_l2 + vehiclebrand_l2 + actual_sales_edmunds_l1 + isSummer + isWinter", data=window).fit()
index = df2[(df2.month == 10) & (df2.year == 2015)].index[0] -1
print result.predict(df2)[index]
```